# How do I implement a priority queue with explicit links (using a triply linked datastructure)?

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, priority-queue

I am trying to implement a priority queue, using a triply linked data structure. I want to understand how to **implement *sink* and *swim* operations**, because when you use an array, you can just compute the index of that array and that's it. Which doesn't make sense when you use a triply-linked DS.

Also I want to understand **how to correctly insert something in the right place**, because when you use an array, you can just insert in the end and do a swim operation, which puts everything in the right place, how exactly do I compute that "end" in a linked DS?

Another problem would be **removing the element with the biggest priority**. To do that, for an array implementation, we just swap the last element with the first (the root) one and then, after removing the last element, we sink down the first one.

(This is a task from Sedgewick).

Comment: You did not explained what is ` triply linked data structure`

Comment: @MBo look at my code. 1 node has 3 links, 1 to parent, and 2 to children.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I posted this in case someone gets stuck doing this exercise from Sedgewick, because he doesn’t provide a solution for it.

I have written an implementation for maximum oriented priority queue, which can be modified according for any priority.

What I do is assign a size to each subtree of the binary tree, which can be defined recursively as size(x.left) + size(x.right) + 1. I do this do be able to find the last node inserted, to be able to insert and delete maximum in the right order.

How sink() works:
Same as in the implementation with an array. We just compare x.left with x.right and see which one is bigger and swap the data in x and max(x.left, x.right), moving down until we bump into a node, whose data is <= x.data or a node that doesn’t have any children.

How swim() works:
Here I just go up by doing x = x.parent, and swapping the data in x and x.parent, until x.parent == null, or x.data <= x.parent.

How max() works:
It just returns root.data.

How delMax() works:
I keep the last inserted node in a separate field, called lastInserted. So, I first swap root.data with lastInserted.data. Then I remove lastInserted by unhooking a reference to it, from its parent. Then I reset the lastInserted field to a node that was inserted before. Also we must not forget to decrease the size of every node on the path from root to the deleted node by 1. Then I sink the root data down.

How insert() works:
I make a new root, if the priority queue is empty. If it’s not empty, I check the sizes of x.left and x.right, if x.left is bigger in size than x.right, I recursively call insert for x.right, else I recursively call insert for x.left. When a null node is reached I return new Node(data, 1). After all the recursive calls are done, I increase the size of all the nodes on the path from root to the newly inserted node.

Here are the pictures for insert():

[image]

And here's my java code:

```java
public class LinkedPQ<Key extends Comparable<Key>>{
    private class Node{
        int N;
        Key data;
        Node parent, left, right;
        public Node(Key data, int N){
            this.data = data; this.N = N;
        }
    }
    // fields
    private Node root;
    private Node lastInserted;
    //helper methods
    private int size(Node x){
        if(x == null) return 0;
        return x.N;
    }
    private void swim(Node x){
        if(x == null) return;
        if(x.parent == null) return; // we're at root
        int cmp = x.data.compareTo(x.parent.data);
        if(cmp > 0){
            swapNodeData(x, x.parent);
            swim(x.parent);
        }
    }
    private void sink(Node x){
        if(x == null) return;
        Node swapNode;
        if(x.left == null && x.right == null){
            return;
        }
        else if(x.left == null){
            swapNode = x.right;
            int cmp = x.data.compareTo(swapNode.data);
            if(cmp < 0)
                swapNodeData(swapNode, x);
        } else if(x.right == null){
            swapNode = x.left;
            int cmp = x.data.compareTo(swapNode.data);
            if(cmp < 0)
                swapNodeData(swapNode, x);
        } else{
            int cmp = x.left.data.compareTo(x.right.data);
            if(cmp >= 0){
                swapNode = x.left;
            } else{
                swapNode = x.right;
            }
            int cmpParChild = x.data.compareTo(swapNode.data);
            if(cmpParChild < 0) {
                swapNodeData(swapNode, x);
                sink(swapNode);
            }
        }
    }
    private void swapNodeData(Node x, Node y){
        Key temp = x.data;
        x.data = y.data;
        y.data = temp;
    }
    private Node insert(Node x, Key data){
        if(x == null){
            lastInserted = new Node(data, 1);
            return lastInserted;
        }
        // compare left and right sizes see where to go
        int leftSize = size(x.left);
        int rightSize = size(x.right);

        if(leftSize <= rightSize){
            // go to left
            Node inserted = insert(x.left, data);
            x.left = inserted;
            inserted.parent = x;
        } else{
            // go to right
            Node inserted = insert(x.right, data);
            x.right = inserted;
            inserted.parent = x;
        }
        x.N = size(x.left) + size(x.right) + 1;
        return x;
    }
    private Node resetLastInserted(Node x){
        if(x == null) return null;
        if(x.left == null && x.right == null) return x;
        if(size(x.right) < size(x.left))return resetLastInserted(x.left);
        else                            return resetLastInserted(x.right);
    }
    // public methods
    public void insert(Key data){
        root = insert(root, data);
        swim(lastInserted);
    }
    public Key max(){
        if(root == null) return null;
        return root.data;
    }
    public Key delMax(){
        if(size() == 1){
            Key ret = root.data;
            root = null;
            return ret;
        }
        swapNodeData(root, lastInserted);
        Node lastInsParent = lastInserted.parent;
        Key lastInsData = lastInserted.data;
        if(lastInserted == lastInsParent.left){
            lastInsParent.left = null;
        } else{
            lastInsParent.right = null;
        }

        Node traverser = lastInserted;

        while(traverser != null){
            traverser.N--;
            traverser = traverser.parent;
        }

        lastInserted = resetLastInserted(root);

        sink(root);

        return lastInsData;
    }
    public int size(){
        return size(root);
    }
    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return size() == 0;
    }
}
```